# Match appearance of buttons

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have two buttons (both working btw..I just need to change the appearance of them to match)

First button opens a print preview page, the second button opens the web browser print dialogue screen.  I want to change the second button to match the first.
Is there anyway I can use a HREF on the second button and use an onclick...so it will use the same template for the button instead of fixing this through css?

First Button:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:right">
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Route", new { id = Id })'>
<button>Print Preview</button>
</a>    
</div>
```

looks like:
[image]

second button:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:right">
<br />
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print();" />
</div>
```

looks like:
[image]

Comment: The problem is what exactly?

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS?

Comment: What's exactly problem, please ask proper question

Comment: did you not read the question? I want both buttons to match appearance

Comment: Please Css also add in your question? so you need your question;s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:right">
<br />
<a onclick="window.print();">
<button>Print</button>
</a>  
</div>
```